# Why / where am I getting stuck in an infinite loop

Tags: java, binary-tree, infinite-loop

I am currently trying to take a text file, and break the text file into words. I am then attempting to store each word as a node in a binary tree. After doing so I also try to print the binary tree. For some reason when i run my code i am now getting caught in an infinite loop but i don't understand where or why that is if you can see where i am getting caught that would be a great help thanks

```
public class Tester {

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

    Tester run = new Tester();
    run.it();

}

public void it() throws FileNotFoundException { 

    BTree theTree = new BTree();

    String str = this.readInFile();

    int position = 0;

    String newWord = this.breakIntoWords(str, position);

    while(newWord != null){

        theTree.add(newWord);

        newWord = this.breakIntoWords(str, position);

    }

    theTree.print();

}

public String readInFile() throws FileNotFoundException {


    String myFile = "";
    int numWords = 0;

    Scanner myScan = new Scanner(new File("Dracula.txt"));

    while(myScan.hasNext() == true) {

        myFile += myScan.nextLine() + " ";

    }

    return myFile;

}

public String breakIntoWords(String myFile, int position) {

    String nextWord = null;

    char next = myFile.charAt(position);
    next = Character.toLowerCase(next);

    // First trim beginning
    while (((next < 'a') || (next > 'z')) && !Character.isDigit(next)) {

        position++;
        next = myFile.charAt(position);
        next = Character.toLowerCase(next);

    }

    // Now pull only letters or numbers until we hit a space
    while(!Character.isWhitespace(next)) {

        if (Character.isLetterOrDigit(next)) {

            nextWord += myFile.charAt(position);

        }

        position++; 
        next = myFile.charAt(position);

    }

    return nextWord;

}

public class BTree {

private BTNode root;
private int nodeCount;


public boolean add(String word){

    BTNode myNode = new BTNode(word);

    if(root == null){

        root = myNode;
        nodeCount++;
        return true;

    }

    if(findNode(word)){

        int tmp = myNode.getNumInstance();
        tmp++;
        myNode.setNumInstance(tmp);
        return false;

    }

    BTNode temp = root;

    while(temp != null){

        if(word.compareTo(temp.getMyWord()) < 0) {

            if(temp.getRightChild() == null){

                temp.setLeftChild(myNode);
                nodeCount++;
                return true;

            } else {

                temp = temp.getRightChild();

            }

        } else {

                if(temp.getLeftChild() == null){

                    temp.setLeftChild(myNode);
                    nodeCount++;
                    return true;

                } else {

                    temp = temp.getLeftChild();

                }

        }

    }

    return false;

}

public boolean findNode(String word) {
    return mySearch(root, word);
}

private boolean mySearch(BTNode root, String word) {
    if (root == null) {
        return false;
    }

    if ((root.getMyWord().compareTo(word) < 0)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        if (word.compareTo(root.getMyWord()) > 0) {
            return mySearch(root.getLeftChild(), word);
        } else {
            return mySearch(root.getRightChild(), word);
        }
    }
}

public void print() {
    printTree(root);
}

private void printTree(BTNode root) {
    if (root == null) {
        System.out.print(".");
        return;
    }

    printTree(root.getLeftChild());
    System.out.print(root.getMyWord());
    printTree(root.getRightChild());

}

public int wordCount() {

    return nodeCount;

}
```

Comment: Have you tried debugger?

Comment: I've never used one before . . . I'm fairly new to code

Comment: Not a Java guy, but in .NET you can click Pause when running code. I assume Java also allows debugging of some sort, since it is almost 2015 not 1995. Failing that, write out debugging text in any way possible to figure out where your code goes wrong.

Comment: Where?!?! am i wrong or you are initializing the same class inside it's own main method?

Comment: @tglauninger You won't get far in programming if you don't learn to use it..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You repeatedly call `this.breakIntoWords(str, position)` with the same `str` and `position`, using its return value to decide when to stop. Since nothing changes from the one iteration to the next, the loop never terminates.

Comment: ok I had intended for the increment of position within the breakIntoWords method is there anyway in which i can increment position within the method and have the value outside the method also be incremented?